# Finding maximum surface area of a box with fixed diagonal - issue with Lagrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Consider a box with dimensions $x_1, x_2, x_3$ whose diagonal is $1$ (i.e. $x_1 ^2+ x_2^2+ x_3^2 = 1$ ). Its surface area is $2(x_1x_2 + x_2x_3 + x_1x_3)$. I am trying to find such a box with maximal surface area. When I use Lagrange multipliers I get that there is no maximum, which is strange because this problem is assigned in a textbook. I am not sure if my reasoning is mistaken, or if there is really no solution.

So the problem is
$$\min f(x) = -(x_1x_2 + x_2x_3 + x_1x_3)$$
$$\text{s.t. } \hspace{0.1cm }h(x) = x_1 ^2+ x_2^2+ x_3^2 - 1 = 0$$
with the implicit assumption that $x_1, x_2, x_3 > 0$. Assuming there is a local minimum, by the Lagrange multiplier theorem, there exists a real number $-\dfrac {\lambda}{2}$ such that
$$\nabla f(x) - \dfrac {\lambda}{2} \nabla h(x) = 0.$$

Now
$$\nabla f(x) = -\begin{bmatrix}x_2 + x_3\\ x_1 + x_3\\ x_1 + x_2 \end{bmatrix} \text{and } \nabla h(x) = \begin{bmatrix}2x_1\\ 2x_2 \\ 2x_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

This gives the system of equations
$$
\begin{align*}
\lambda x_1 + x_2 + x_3 & = 0\\
 x_1 + \lambda x_2 + x_3 & = 0\\
 x_1 + x_2 + \lambda x_3 & = 0
\end{align*}$$

Adding all of these equations together yields
$$(1 + \lambda)(x_1 + x_2 + x_3) = 0$$
If $\lambda \not = -1$, then we have $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0$. However, this is not possible under the implicit assumption that $x_1, x_2, x_3 > 0$, so we conclude that $\lambda = -1$.

But if $\lambda = -1$, then the above system becomes
$$\begin{align}
- x_1 + x_2 + x_3 & = 0\\
 x_1  - x_2 + x_3 & = 0\\
 x_1 + x_2 - x_3 & = 0
\end{align}$$

whose only solution is $(0, 0, 0)$, which is unacceptable.

Comment: Shouldn't the factor $(1+\lambda)$ be $(2+\lambda)$?

Comment: @peterag Yes, thank you. Let me see if that changes things

Comment: @peterag Yes, that was the issue. Using $\lambda = -2$ makes the corresponding matrix singular, as desired.

Comment: To take the question of the 'unanswered' q, why don't you add the solution below?

Comment: And accept it of course!

Comment: Why did you introduce the negative and change the problem to a minimization? I'm always in favor of the simplest approach possible.

Comment: @TedShifrin Because the Lagrange multiplier theorem I have deals with minimization, and at the time I did not have the patience to think if the Lagrance multipliers theorem applies to maximizers as well. But now that I think of it for a minute, of course it does; if $x$ is a maximizer of $f$, then there exists a $\lambda$ such that $-f(x) + \lambda h(x) = 0$, so there exists a $\mu$ ( which is $- \lambda$) such that $f(x) + \mu h(x) = 0$.

Comment: @peterag Sure; I am writing an answer right now

Comment: You're going to get *candidates* for local extrema; they may be constrained saddle points, as well. So I am puzzled by a theorem that "guarantees" (?) a constrained minimum, when one might not even exist.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm sorry for the confusion, I did not express my concern clearly. My original worry was that the following situation could happen: there is a local maxima at $x^*$ with $\nabla h(x^*) \not = 0$, but there is no $\lambda$ such that $\nabla f(x) + \lambda \nabla h(x^*) = 0$. As I said above, when I thought about it for $2$ seconds after the fact, I realized this situation can't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forming the lagrangian

$$
L = x y + y z + z x +\lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)
$$

the stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = 0 = \cases{2 \lambda  x+y+z\\ 2 \lambda  y+x+z\\ 2 \lambda  z+x+y\\ x^2+y^2+z^2-1}
$$

now to solve this system of equations, first we will try to solve

$$
\cases{2 \lambda  x+y+z=0\\ 2 \lambda  y+x+z=0\\ 2 \lambda  z+x+y=0}
$$

but the unique solution gives $x=y=z=0$ which is unacceptable. To have a non trivial solution we need that

$$
\det\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 \lambda  & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 \lambda  & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 2 \lambda  \\
\end{array}
\right) = 2 (\lambda +1) (2 \lambda -1)^2 = 0\ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$

so this operation determines the feasible $\lambda$. Now taking $x,y$ for instance from

$$
\cases{2 \lambda  x+y+z=0\\ 2 \lambda  y+x+z=0}
$$

and substituting into $x^2+y^2+z^2-1$ we get

$$
\frac{2 z^2}{(2 \lambda +1)^2}+z^2-1=0
$$

and solving for $z$ after substituting $\lambda$ with the solutions from $(1)$ we will have all the stationary points from the lagrangian: after that we should choose the feasible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by "peter a g" in the comments, the issue is: The equation
$$(1 + \lambda)(x_1 + x_2 + x_3) = 0$$

should instead be
$$(2 + \lambda)(x_1 + x_2 + x_3) = 0$$
This leads us to $\lambda = -2$, and solving the corresponding system gives $x_1 = x_2 = x_3$. Plugging this into $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 = 1$ yields $x _1 = x_2 = x_3 = \dfrac {1}{\sqrt 3}.$

Since the constraint set $C$ is compact, $f(x) = x_1x_2 + x_2 x_3 + x_1 x_3$ (restricted to $C$) achieves a global maximum on $C$. To finish, we would have to find all solutions of the system obtained using the Lagrange multipleir method, and check all of them.